# Data is overlapping from original container

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with displaying some data - it's overflowing because of the client set width.
Here is content coming from the admin panel:

```html
<div class="content-block">                   
  <div class="college-details">                 
    <div class="media-right">
      <div class="detail" style="padding:15px">
        <p>
        
        <!-- <?php echo $data->about;?> -->
        <table style="width:1391pt" border="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="height: 259.2pt; vertical-align: bottom; white-space: normal; width: 1381pt;">From the CEO and Provost<br /> 
                welcome to our University<br /> <br /> Universities are powerful institutions; they play a key role in our 
                driving economic and social development through both the provision of education and through the process of research, innovation and knowledge transfer.
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
        </p>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you tell me how to solve this in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the client style using `!important` with your width in you stylesheet. Example:

```css
.detail table {
  width: 300px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-block">                   
  <div class="college-details">                 
    <div class="media-right">
      <div class="detail" style="padding:15px">
        <p>
        
        <!-- <?php echo $data->about;?> -->
        <table style="width:1391pt" border="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="height: 259.2pt; vertical-align: bottom; white-space: normal; width: 1381pt;">From the CEO and Provost<br /> 
                welcome to our University<br /> <br /> Universities are powerful institutions; they play a key role in our 
                driving economic and social development through both the provision of education and through the process of research, innovation and knowledge transfer.
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
        </p>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: solution  1: use width: x% / solution 2: use @media in order to have one style per type of device / solution 3: implement bootstrap. It is realy up to you, depending of your need

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work...

div {
  z-index: 1; //any integer value
}

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at following code snippet. I'm not sure what width you have set to the `div` with `detail` class. I've set the `overflow-x: scroll` which adds a scroll when inner content is exceeding the width of parent element. Hope this helps.

```css
div.detail {
  width: 250px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-block">
  <div class="college-details">
    <div class="media-right">
      <div class="detail" style="padding:15px">
        <p>
          <table style="width:1391pt" border="1" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="height: 259.2pt; vertical-align: bottom; white-space: normal; width: 1381pt;">From the CEO and Provost<br /> welcome to our University<br /> <br /> Universities are powerful institutions; they play a key role in our driving economic and social development through both the provision of education and through the process
                  of research, innovation and knowledge transfer.
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </p>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding a max-width to the table

```
    .detail table {
       max-width: 100vw; 
    }
```

you could find the snippet here where I have also removed the padding for the div with class detail: https://jsfiddle.net/b4zw9ch5/